# Non-Systematic Binary Linear Codes

Tags: linear-algebra, coding-theory

If a binary code is systematic then the $k$ information bits are preserved in the codeword and $r$ redundant bits are appended to them.

In the case of a non-systematic code, are the $k$ information bits still preserved in the codeword but in a random order or are they not necessarily contained?

I guess I can always find an equivalent systematic code with a generator matrix in standard form, but if I choose not to, can I prove that the $k$ bits are not necessarily contained in the codeword?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any linear map $T:\{0,1\}^k \rightarrow \{0,1\}^{n}$ where $n=k+r$ defines a linear code. To obtain a good code, you need more properties of this map, of course.

So, yes a non-systematic code need not necessarily contain the $k$ bits as some subset of the codeword coordinates.